# Error when training neural network input idmention mistmatch

Tags: python, neural-network

I got the following error when trying to build a neural_net:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_6_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()
```

Here is my codes:

```
print(np.shape(text_tf_train)) # shape=(70000, 73399)
vectorized_training=text_tf_train[0:60000]
y_train_neralnettr =y_train_neralnet[0:60000]
vectorized_validation=text_tf_train[60000:70000]
y_validation_neralnet=y_train_neralnet[60000:70000]




model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(4500, activation = "relu", input_shape=(73399, )))
# Hidden - Layers
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(1500, activation = "relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(500, activation = "relu"))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(50, activation = "relu"))
# Output- Layer
model.add(layers.Dense(20, activation = "sigmoid"))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer="adam",
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit( np.array(vectorized_training), np.array(y_train_neralnettr),
          batch_size=2000,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(np.array(vectorized_validation), np.array(y_validation_neralnet)))
```

My inputs are 60000 vectorized messages and 20 different labels that need to be classified. I don't understand what they mean by have 2 dimension. It is an input of dimension 73399.

Comment: It literally means, that the data that you are passing to the dense_6_input is not what it expects. It's expecting a tensor/array with a different sort of dimension.

Comment: Ok but my vectorized training is of shape(60000,73399) so it should be correct not? How do I correct this error. Here dens_6 is the first hidden layer.

Comment: In your first dense layer you specify that the `input_shape = (73399, )` but you are passing it an array of shape`(60000, )`

Comment: can you update your code with shapes of all your x, y.Both train and validation. This model should work if your shapes are right

Comment: What is the shape of `y_train_neralnet`?